# How to get attributes in Groovy via xpath

Tags: xml, groovy, soapui

Facing issue in getting attribute value of xml using groovy script.

I am having a CDATA xml. I was able to parse the XML till CDATA. But, I am unable to write the XPATH for the attributes present in the Node. Please find the sample below.

> NodeName=Item, attribute=ItemID

```
<Item ItemID="XXX-XXXXX"/>
```

e.g.

```
<Item ItemID="abc-defg"/>
```

groovy script:

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder
respXmlHolder = new XmlHolder(messageExchange.getResponseContentAsXml())
respXmlHolder.declareNamespace("ns1","http://example.com/types")
CDATAXml = respXmlHolder.getNodeValue("//ns1:Response[1]/result[1]")
log.info(CDATAXml)
CDATAXmlHolder = new XmlHolder(CDATAXml)
Item = CDATAXmlHolder.getNodeValue("//ItemID")
log.info("Item = $Item")
assert '397-0109'== Item.@ItemID.text()
```

Can someone please help me in getting the value of ItemID attribute using groovy script in SOAPUI.

Comment: Sample xml => <Item ItemID="abc-defg"/>

Comment: Have you tried the documentation? http://www.soapui.org/Functional-Testing/working-with-cdata.html

Comment: We have tried it. But, our CDATA xml should be parsed and then get the attribute value not the node value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this way. it worked. Thank You.

```
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder
import groovy.lang.*
import java.util.*
import com.eviware.soapui.support.UISupport

def xmlStr = """<OrderLines>
<OrderLine>
<Item ItemId='397-0109'/>
<Item ItemId='125-5449'/>
<Item ItemId='523-7449'/>
</OrderLine>
</OrderLines>"""

def xmlParse = new XmlParser().parseText( xmlStr )
def ItemId = [:]
println "Write out the Attributes for each node"
xmlParse.OrderLine.Item.each {
ItemId = it.attributes()
log.info(ItemId)
}
```